# How to discover reliable speed to use a logic gate?

Tags: digital-logic, datasheet, clock-speed

It seems to be very hard to get consistent numbers for the performance of logic chips. I am interested in using the SN74F574 component (8 bit register).

Looking at DigiKey, when I search for the component it shows a results grid with a clock frequency of 100Mhz and max propagation delay of 8.5ns. This is inconsistent as 8.5ns is equal to 117Mhz, a not insignificant difference in my opinion. Should I take the lower of these two numbers?

[image]

So I open up the datasheet of the component and inside it has a grid showing the propagation delays. The maximum value in the grid is 35ns and so surely the only safe way to use the part is to ensure you can handle the maximum. So that would give an actual speed of 28Mhz.

[image]

So do I clock at 28Mhz, 100Mhz or 117Mhz? Why don't datasheets make your life easy and specify a clock speed (or the matching ns) that it can be clocked at?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clip from just a few inches above the part your clipped:

[image]

Comment: @PhilWright, if you look at the datasheet for a nand gate or something, it won't have this spec. Because it doesn't have a clock signal.

Answer (score 1):

you might be more interested in these parts

[image]

**- If you are really serious about speed you chose CML (current mode logic).**

- If you want the best currently available in CMOS (voltage mode logic)
- then you choose 74ALVCxxx  (or 74ALVC2xxx if avail is better) both 25 Ohm source  in Octal D 3state  ( Similar used in ARM Cortex )

  **- 150MHz min 300MHz typ and much more with skill**

*- 74F is old TTL stuff, nothing special except big Iol currents.*

> - If you want the most speed in any family;

- use controlled impedance tracks matched to source with matched active termination

  - (i.e. pull-up/down R to bias at threshold voltage
  - (1.3V for TTL , Vcc/2 for CMOS)  this may get you 50% more speed.
    .
- for TTL use the upper Vcc tolerance voltage and run hot
- for CMOS, use with least pF load per pin and operate cold but with low Vcc (1.9)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum frequency is assuming you are correctly designing the circuitry around the chip.

Based on the data sheet, 7ps is possible if the shift register is the only gate in the cycle path (for low to high transition; you can use differential logic to guarantee the active edge is always rising if you need to run at 100MHz ... it's maximum not practical :P). 35ps you mentioned is the high end of a four gate cycle path.

So, if you keep this as the only gate in the cycle path,you can clock it at 100MHz; hence the maximum clock speed.  Obviously the minimum clock speed has no bounds since you can add many stages after this gate before another sequential element, or could heavily load it so that the transition takes much longer.

As for the 100MHz vs. 117MHz maximum ... this is really splitting hairs.  Since a shift register will need at least another sequential element to create a cycle path, there will be additional delay (setup time).  So even though the gate may take 7ps to switch, the capture flop most likely needs at least 3ps setup time.  And the launching flop will also have some finite delay.

Comment: I thought the column with the number gates related to the internal number of gate levels. I didn't realise it meant the fanout. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilWright: Actually I think you are right.  Still, my answer stands with slight modification.  It will work assuming you are only using the shift register in your cycle to cycle path.  You can pipeline your architecture if you must for this to work.

Comment: Remember that F series parts were notoriously hard to work with because the fast signal edges mean a lot of high frequency content, but no provision is made for modern SI practice, like impedance matching.

Comment: yes I remember using 74F when I was a "green weenie" , the term given to us young grads.  It was the fastest I knew how to use at the time.